# How to verify of PGP-compatible signatures in C++?

Tags: c++, signature, verification, gnupg, pgp

I have to digitally sign a file. The verification of its signature is done later inside a C++ application and needed to protect the software from being tampered.

I would like to use existing command line tools such as those from GnuPG or OpenSSL to generate keys, manage key hierarchies and trust and finally to generate the signatures for the files.

However, I am not sure e.g. how to deal with e.g. PGP keys in my C++ application. Due licensing constraints we cannot use GPL-based libraries such as libgcrypt or GPGme. All other libraries seem to provide building cryptographic building blocks for developers. But I can hardly see an easy way to load and deal with PGP keys for example. Building the PGP-compatible suff ourselves seems a big effor and most likely error prone.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What keeps you from using those command line tools you mentioned (which you *can* call from inside your C++ program) for everything, avoiding the GPL issue completely?

Comment: IANAL, but GPL-based libraires are not subject to GPL licensing when statically linked against your program. As long as you wget the binaries and the header, you are good to go. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception )

Comment: @georgesl Only some of them (which is why it is an *exception* and not part of the normal license). This is also the reason the LGPL exists.

Comment: GPL libraries *do* make your binaries linking to them subject to GPL licensing. **LGPL** libraries make your binaries linking to them subject to LGPL licensing, *unless* you ship your binaries in a way that they could be *re-linked* with modified versions of the LGPL libraries. GPL libraries **with link exception** do not make your binaries subject to LGPL licensing *as stated in the individual exception*.

Comment: I cannot call a binary from within the application as the user might want to attack the software protection by providing a tampered/evil version of these tools. E.g. the signature verification might always succeed.

Comment: @Stefan: If an attacker could modify system binaries identified by full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/gpg`), your system is *dead*, and nothing your application could attempt to do could save your security.

Comment: I know that the application is not going to be "safe" in terms of super-safety. It is just about copy-protecting the application and making it as hard as possible for any attacker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't sound as a technical question but a legal one.